# Android: how to combine the paths of two shapes and remove overlap?

Tags: android, graphics, path

I want to create a speech balloon type shape, where there is a rectangle or ellipse with a triangular shape jutting out of it.

How I'm attempting to do this is to create a Path object that combines the triangle with the other shape (round rect).

I'm doing it as follows:

```
Path path = new Path();
// Create triangular segment

Point drawOffset = getAttributes().getDrawOffset();
int leaderGap = getAttributes().getLeaderGapWidth();

// Recall that we have a coordinate system where (0,0) is the
// bottom midpoint of the annotation rectangle.

// the point to left of gap
int x1 = -leaderGap/2;
int y1 = 0;

// the point to right of gap
int x2 = leaderGap/2;
int y2 = 0;

// The point where we're drawing to; the end of the pointy segment of triangle
int x3 = -drawOffset.x;
int y3 = drawOffset.y;

path.moveTo(x2, y2);
path.lineTo(x3, y3);
path.lineTo(x1, y1);
// path.close();


// Add the rectangular portion to the path
path.addRoundRect(backgroundShape, 5, 5, Path.Direction.CW);
```

The problem is that the roundRect is a closed path, so its edge shows through underneath the triangular section.

A picture's worth a thousand words, so here you go:

[image: Rounded balloon]

What I want is for the line segment between those two endpoints of the triangle to disappear, so that it looks like one seamless path.

If all I were doing were a straight rectangle, I could create the whole path myself from scratch.  But I'd like to do the rounded corners, and it'd be a bit of a paint to do that with the Path (yes I know you can do quad to and arcTo but it's still not as clean a solution as I'd like).

So in general, is it possible to combine two paths and create a single union object that traces the perimeter of both?

Answer (score 2):

Yes this is possible as of API 19. You can perform logical operations between 2 paths. As in your case, you can create a UNION of the two paths, using [`Path.op()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Path.html#op(android.graphics.Path,%20android.graphics.Path.Op)). For a complete list of the operations that can be performed refer [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Path.Op.html).

Answer (score 0):

I can't see a convenient way to combine paths in this manner.  I would normally achieve this by manually drawing the rounded rectangular parts with Path.arcTo() and Path.lineTo(), it's a little extra effort but it will achieve the result you are looking for.

Another option which is perhaps more flexible if you decide to change the theme is to use a [ninepatch drawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/NinePatch.html) there's even an editor to let you create them called [Draw 9-patch](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/draw9patch.html)